# Uploading a file in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I want to upload a .txt file using Cypress. Is there a way to make Cypress choose the file or do I have to manually select the file every time?
[image: Clicking the 'Choose file' button]
[image: window pops up]
The 'window pops up' is where I want cypress to select a file, is it possible?

Thanks for all the help

[image: html of the button]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [selectFile](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/selectfile) method from cypress to upload the file.

```js
cy.get('[title="Choose File"]').selectFile('path/to/txt') //Selects the File
cy.get('input[title="Upload"]').click() //Clicks upload button
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to target the `input[type="file"]` to add the file to the input

```js
cy.get('input[type="file"]')
  .selectFile(fileName)
  .trigger('input');               // may also be required               

cy,get('input[type="submit"]).click();
```

or by finding the label and using `sibling()` to move to the input

```js
cy.contains('label', 'Choose file')
  .sibling('input[type="file"]')
  .selectFile(fileName)
  .trigger('input');               // may also be required               

cy,get('input[type="submit"]).click();
```